# Side by side divs

Tags: css, html

How to place two divs side by side with splitter between them?

That's what I mean:

[image]

I assume that html layout can looks something like this:

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="left"></div>
    <div id="splitter"></div>
    <div id="right"></div>
</div>
```

or

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="left">
        <div id="splitter"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="right"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: there are almost infinite possibilitys to achive this. what have you tried till now? have you asked google for such a solution and used the search on SO?

Comment: in addition, you should provide more information. should the divs have the same height ? should they grow with the content or use the full possible height? should the parts have a specific width or grow wenn i resize my browser?

Comment: Any working approach will fit my needs. 1) divs should have the same fixed height; 2) left and right panes should be stretched within available space;

Comment: +1 for the image. But what's that splitter supposed to consist of? If it doesn't have any real content, you should try to avoid using HTML for it, and use pure CSS instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

html:

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="left"></div>
    <div id="splitter"></div>
    <div id="right"></div>
</div>
```

css:

```
#container{
 width:990px; //or 100%
}
#left{
 width:300px; //or 30%
 float:left;
}
#splitter{
 width:90px; //or 5%
 float:left;
}
#right{
 600px; //or 65%
 float:left;
}
```

Comment: Doesn't work: right pane is always located on the next string (at least in IE8 and Chrome 7)

Comment: do they have any padding or margin? if so remove them or subtract them from the widths.

Comment: There is no any padding or margin and the total width of left, right pane and splitter is equal to container width. I rid of this issue by adding absolute position for panes and relative for splitter. It works for me fine. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

put "float: left" on #left and #splitter, but as oezi said there are lots of ways to do this

Comment: The same problem as here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4285483/side-by-side-divs/4285526#4285526. But the right pane is right-aligned on the next string.

Answer (score 0):

Both are possible but I would go for the 2nd one since you can use float:left for the left div and float:right for right and since splitter is in the left div it goes to the correct spot.

Comment: If so, content of the right pane is aligned along the right side of the left pane (on the left of the splitter).