# Is it ever useful to specify percentages (ie. width: 25%) for divs in CSS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I noticed questions asking about positions and dimensions of divs get asked a lot, observe:

1. [Side by side divs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4285483/side-by-side-divs)
2. [divs side by side in container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10656698/divs-side-by-side-in-container)
3. [2 divs side by side](http://welovecss.com/showthread.php?t=465)

But I find a great deal --granted not all-- hard code the dimensions of the div. I mostly work with percentages as I prefer to have my divs be in relative positions. I start out by specifying a width/height percentage in my `css` file like so

```
div #menu {
   width: 75%;
   min-width: 75%;
}
```

but then having to force the minimum width with jQuery later like so:

```
function onload ()
{
   $( "#menu" ).css( "min-width", 0.75 * window.width() ) );
}
```

I feel like a bit of a moron declaring CSS code all over the place, so my question is this: Should I even bother specifying the width/min-width property in the css stylesheet, or is there a better way to handle these situations.

Here is a [jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/pukster/tDBSf/1/) which illustrates the problem I am running into.

Comment: ?? You don't have to do that with JavaScript ...

Comment: ... and it really won't work anyway when people change their browser window size after the page loads.

Comment: I don't think you even need min-width in this case, since you are already using %'s. Why do you need to specify it in JS?

Comment: I find if you don't specify a min width, the div doesn't use the whole space

Comment: @Pointy that can be fixed with an `onresize` handler.

Comment: @raina77ow The percentage in the stylesheet is calculated relative to the containing DIV, not the window as the JS does.

Comment: Is there really a space between `div` and `#menu` in your CSS?  If so that'd be a problem - it only selects `#menu` when it's got a `<div>` paremt element.

Comment: @pointy I don't understand what you mean

Comment: You really haven't posted enough for the situation to be clear. What does your HTML look like?

Comment: @Pointy very well, let me post a minimal jsfiddle script, give me 5 minutes

Comment: @Pointy I included a jsfiddle example

Comment: @puk one problem you're suffering from is that your selectors all look wrong to me - "div #A" means "the element with id 'A' and nested inside some `<div>`", and not "the `<div>` element named 'A'".

Comment: @Pointy I see, let me change that and see if it fixes the problem

Comment: I typed in an answer and an updated version of the jsfiddle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some problems:

1. Your CSS was implicitly relying on the `<body>` to stretch out to the size of the window. That's not how things work; you need an explicit rule:

   ```
   body, html { width: 100%; height: 100%; padding: 0; }
   ```
2. Your selectors are wrong.  The space in "div #A" should be removed; in fact so should the "div".  When selecting by "id" all you need is the "id" unless you're doing some sort of qualification for a dynamic widget (like "body.touch #foo" to apply a style only on touch screen devices).
3. In jsfiddle, you don't supply the whole HTML markup. The tool does that for you.  What you put in the HTML panel is just the `<body>` contents.

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/Pointy/tDBSf/2/) is a fixed version of your code.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Pointy's advice I figured out the problem. I was using `div #A {...}` when I should have been using `#A {...}`. Afterwards, I also stretched the body to 100% with this line:

```
body {
   margin: 0px;
   height: 100%;
   min-height: 100%;
   min-width: 100%;
}
```

And then it worked as expected. See here [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pukster/tDBSf/3/)